# AFNetworking PostPath php Parameters are null

Tags: php, post, afnetworking

I am trying to send a username and password from an iOS app using AFNetworking framework to a php script. The iOS app continues to receive status code 401 which I defined to be "not enough parameters". I have tried returning the "username" from the php script to the iOS app and receive .

Based on what I've been investigating so far, it seems as though:

1) The php script is not decoding the POST parameters properly

2) The iOS app is not sending the POST parameters properly

The following is the iOS function

```
- (IBAction)startLoginProcess:(id)sender
{

NSString *usernameField = usernameTextField.text;
NSString *passwordField = passwordTextField.text;

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:usernameField,        @"username", passwordField, @"password", nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/~alejandroe1790/edella_admin/"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];

[httpClient postPath:@"login.php" parameters:parameters
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                 NSLog(@"operation hasAcceptableStatusCode: %d", [operation.response statusCode]);
             }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error with request");
                 NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
             }];

}
```

The following is the php script

```
function checkLogin()
{

    // Check for required parameters
    if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
        //Put parameters into local variables
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT Password FROM Admin WHERE Username=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($resultpassword);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            break;
        }
        $stmt->close();

        // Username or password invalid
        if ($password == $resultpassword) {
            sendResponse(100, 'Login successful');
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            sendResponse(400, 'Invalid Username or Password');
            return false;
        }
    }
    sendResponse(401, 'Not enough parameters');
    return false;
}
```

I feel like I may be missing something. Any assistance would be great.

Comment: what you get if you do var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))); ??

Comment: object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(14) "alejandroe1790"
  ["password"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the parameter encoding to JSON and they are being set to the HTTP Body by the `AFHTTPClient` class. You can get around this and use `$_POST` by not setting the encoding to JSON.

```
- (IBAction)startLoginProcess:(id)sender
{

NSString *usernameField = usernameTextField.text;
NSString *passwordField = passwordTextField.text;

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:usernameField,        @"username", passwordField, @"password", nil];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/~alejandroe1790/edella_admin/"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

[httpClient postPath:@"login.php" parameters:parameters
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                 NSLog(@"operation hasAcceptableStatusCode: %d", [operation.response statusCode]);
             }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error with request");
                 NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
             }];

}
```

However, you can send your parameters as a JSON string if you choose, but you won't be able to use `$_POST` and will need to `json_decode` `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`

```
function checkLogin()
{
    global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
    // remove the second argument or pass false if you want to use an object
    $user_info = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true);
    // Check for required parameters
    if (isset($user_info["username"]) && isset($user_info["password"]))
    {
        //Put parameters into local variables
        $username = $user_info["username"];
        $password = $user_info["password"];

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT Password FROM Admin WHERE Username=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($resultpassword);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            break;
        }
        $stmt->close();

        // Username or password invalid
        if ($password == $resultpassword) {
            sendResponse(100, 'Login successful');
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            sendResponse(400, 'Invalid Username or Password');
            return false;
        }
    }
    sendResponse(401, 'Not enough parameters');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I attempted both suggestions and received "The network connection was lost" as a localized description of error. I used the var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))); (with json encoding included still) and received "object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(14) "alejandroe1790"
  ["password"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}"

Comment: Yeah you can assign that object to a variable ie `$user_info` and then change your code to use `$user_info->username`. I tested both of my examples above locally and had no issues. The first code I removed the parameter encoding and use the same PHP that you have. In the second example I used your Objective-C code with modified PHP code.

Comment: Not able to get it to work. Maybe I am missing something from the php file. Do i need to include anything at the beginning of the php file?

Comment: Was able to resolve issue, my sendResponse() function was forcing the error. Thanks for the assistance. In case you were curious, this below is the sendResponse() function that wasn't working:
function sendResponse($status = 100, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
{
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    echo $body;
}

Comment: Oh. I just made a dummy one `sendResponse($code, $message)` and then did `header($message, true, $code)`

Comment: @AlejandroEscobar I am having the exact same problem. What did you change in the sendResponse() ?

Comment: @JonathanBrown I will get back to you with a response soon